# printer OKI B430dn worked on Ubuntu 12.04, doesn't on 14.04

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, drivers, printing, cups-lpd

In our office we have several pc's with Ubuntu and a network printer OKI B430dn.

The double-sided option worked well with Ubuntu 12.04 driver (OKI B4300 footmatic/pxlmono) installed with CUPS (via browser).

I installed Ubuntu 14.04. Now the double-sided option doesn't work anymore with Ubuntu 14.04 driver (OKI B4300 footmatic/pxlmono). The option doesn't appear. I tried another B4300 driver (B430 driver don't exist) and the PPD file 1.0 from OKI's website... but this has no effect.

Comment: posiibly related to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/413481/printed-pdf-says-invalidfont-and-offending-command-when-printing-from-chrome

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried what is in the readme of the Oki package?

```
3.0 INSTALLATION
 a) login as root
    # su - root
 b) execute install.sh
    # ./install.sh

5.0 CREATE QUEUE(S)
 a) start a browser
 b) populate location bar with 'http://localhost:631'
 c) follow prompts to create queue
 d) select Make - 'OKI'
 e) select Model - 'OKI B4000 / B400 / MB400 PS'
 f) follow remaining prompts until queue is created
```

Contents of package is:
     COPYING
     OK400PS.ppd
     install.sh
     okijobaccounting
     readme.pdf
     uninstall.sh

Comment: OK, blame me, but I'm confused. How exactly does this  answer the question asked?